# How to find and delete with Firebase in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How can I find and delete this line with title is Apple with Javascript
Thanks

Comment: You should check out the amazing Firebase Documentation where they cover [Filtering and Querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) for specific data. Once you've queried for the node you want to delete (query for Apple in this case). You will know the parent key and can delete the node. [Deleting Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) is also covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteApple(){
 return firebase.database().ref('firebase-test/' + pushID).remove(); 
}
```

According to this doc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

Comment: That's assuming the user knows the id (node key) and typically pushID's are created when the node is written and may not be known afterward. I believe the OP wants to locate that node and then delete it.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the row has title is Apple and delete it,